# Snowflake Information Schema File Formats View - where are all the values?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have noticed a few values are not included in the File Formats View
examples

`SKIP_BLANK_LINES`,
`REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS`,
`VALIDATE_UTF8`,
`EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL`,
`SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK`,
`ENCODING`

There are a few from the non-CSV types too.
Why are they not included?
When are they going to be included?
Where can I find these values while we wait?
I have noticed a few other cases where information schema is missing obvious things - RI relationships anyone?

Answer (score 0):

> *Where can I find these values?*

You could find values for non-default entries using:

```
SELECT GET_DDL('FILE_FORMAT', '<schema>.<file_format_name>');
```

For instance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT PUBLIC.Test
TYPE = 'CSV'
FIELD_DELIMETER = ','
SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE        -- non-default
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_SNULL = FALSE   -- non-default
;


SELECT GET_DDL('FILE_FORMAT', 'PUBLIC.Test');

-- CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT TEST 
--     SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE 
--     EMPTY_FIELD_AS_SNULL = FALSE
-- ;
```

---

> **[DESCRIBE FILE FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-file-format.html)**
>
> Describes the properties and their current values for a file format, as well as the default values **for each property**.

```
DESCRIBE FILE FORMAT PUBLIC.Test;

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
WHERE "property_value" != "property_default";
```